# How I get hints from IntelliJ on ViewBinding class fields when this class is not generated yet?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, intellij-idea, android-view

I was playing around Kotlin and learned about ViewBinding and how it works. It seems quite easy for me but there is one thing I don't understand. I edit activity_main.xml and instantly get hints on ActivityMainBinding instance's fields. For example, I add a new TextView in xml layout and AndroidStudio immediately shows me hints on this View, even though the class has not been generated yet. Is it just an AndroidStudio built-in analyzer feature or something else? Does it really calculate this in real time and allows you to see the class fields that have not yet been generated, but will appear at the next build of the application?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: “Even though the class isn’t generated yet” why do you think this is the case? It generates the new binding class automatically. The compiler is constantly recompiling your Kotlin code as you type it. That’s how it can show you errors before you build the app.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I found ActivityMainBinding.java file in biuld/generated directory, but it changes only when I run application. So there's something under the hood of IntelliJ that I can't see in real time?

Comment: I guess I never really thought about it but that must be the case. The stuff in `build` is where it copies all the relevant code for a build and that gets compiled fully when doing a build. That’s not what it’s looking at to generate code hints and errors as you are programming.